# Obj-C ios AudioToolkit not playing sound

Tags: objective-c, ios, audiotoolbox

When I hard-code the sound name into there, it works, but when I use a random generator to create the string, it doesn't. BTW: This is in Xcode 4.3 and iPhone 5.1 simulator.

---

```
int rand = round(arc4random_uniform(3));
char buf[100];
sprintf(buf,"Sound%d.aifc",rand);
//get the filename of the sound file
NSString *fp=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], fp];
//declare a system sound
SystemSoundID soundID;

//get a path for the sound file
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

//create the sound id
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);

//play the sound
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Comment: Check your assumptions - when you use the random generator, what's the actual filename being set into "buf"? Can you printf it or something to see what it is?

Comment: @Colen I used GDB with breakpoints and it had the correct file name when ran multiple times.(Sound(0,1,2,3).aifc)

Comment: So if the only change you make is to replace "rand" with "2" on the sprintf line, it works properly? No other changes at all?

Comment: That dosen't work. It only works like this: NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"Sound2.aifc"];

Comment: In the debugger, look at the value of "path" when you do it both ways. What's the difference?

Comment: It is correct both ways.

Answer (score 0):

When I run `-[NSBundle mainBundle]` on my machine, it doesn't include a trailing slash.

Change this line:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", 
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], fp];
```

To this:

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 
  stringByAppendingPathComponent:fp];
```

This will do the right thing wether `NSBundle` is adding trailing slashes or not.

Comment: Gravedug, this from march 2012

Comment: I get bored and go through the old unanswereds sometimes :)